# when transfering frontend to laravel, part of the js code does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, frontend

The js file is connected correctly, it is visible when viewing the page code in the browser, but some functions do not work. Function addField and deleteField work just fine. The rest is not but there are no errors in the pannel.

While if I put the whole frontend in a folder like the html file, js file and open this page in the browser, then everything works the way it was intended.

Sorry, the code is clumsy, but I need it in any form:

```js
$("div#photo_0").hide();

$('.show_popup').click(function() {
    var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));
    $(popup_id).show(); 
    $('.overlay_popup').show(); 
})
$('.overlay_popup').click(function() {
    $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide(); 
})

function addField() {
    if ($("#photo div").length < 12) {
        var photo = $("div#photo_0").html();

        if ($("#photo div").length == 2) {
            p_id = 1;
        } else {
            p_id = parseInt(
                $('#photo div')
                    .last()
                    .attr('id')
                    .replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
            ) + 1;
        }
        $("div#photo").append(photo);

        $('div#photo')
            .children()
            .last()
            .attr('id', "p_" + p_id)
            .attr('onclick', "deleteField(" + p_id + ")");
    } else {
        alert("10 photos!")
    }

}
function deleteField(p_id) {
    var id = '#p_' + p_id
    $(id).remove();
}
```

Put already working code in laravel and expect it to work

Comment: From the info you have posted I would say that you did not configure .mix file properly? Can you put a screenshot of it in the commet, too please?

Comment: Is this code run after the document has been loaded? Does `div#photo_0` exist when the script is loaded?